# SQLServer reduce geometry max reduce value

Tags: sql-server, geometry, polygons

I am selecting a number of Geometry types from a SQL server database; when I reduce, I am having issues getting the most reduction without my polygons collapsing in on each other.

```
Select
    Polygon.Reduce(@reduceAmount).ToString()
FROM
    PolygonTable
```

Is there way to reduce to a specific type of Geometry (like a polygon)?